# Wacom One not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wacom-one

I have bought Wacom one Tablet.
After installing the latest drivers from the Wacom website, and plugging in the tablet, it is not recognized. Wacom Tablet Properties state: "No Wacom device connected to your computer".
The driver details are also not displayed in the device manager.

When I plug in the tablet, it is recongized as a generic external screen, but the pen and
the writing capabilities are not working.

After driver installation, wacom pen is written into registry though (although missing from the device manager)

I tried it two different laptops - DELL XPS13 and HP Probook. Both laptops are running Windows 10 with the latest update.

I've also tried executing all recommended steps in the first 10 pages of google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Contact Wacom support.>>>https://www.wacom.com/en-us/support/contact-support

Comment: idk about recent versions, but Wacoms always used to need to be connected before boot, not 'live' while the computer is running.

Comment: Dear Moab, 

I already contacted Wacom support, but they haven't responded.

@Tetsujin - I tried all combinations of computer off / on

Answer (score 0):

The usb port was not working properly